# Can a Toshiba HG6 128 GB M.2 be upgraded to a Samsung 970 PRO 512GB M.2 in an MSI GL72-7RD laptop?

Tags: ssd, m.2

My [MSI GL72-7RD laptop](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GL72-7RD.html) has a [Toshiba HG6 128 GB M.2 (2280) SSD Drive](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/solid-state-drives-ssd/1112330/), and I want upgrade it with a [Samsung 970 PRO 512GB - NVMe PCIe M.2 2280 SSD (MZ-V7P512BW)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07C8Y31G2), but I don’t know if it will work since it seems to have a different socket connector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MSI GL72 7RD supports SATA and NVMe in its M.2 slot.

From the [manufacturer specifications](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GL72-7RD/Specification) we get:

> SSD: 1x M.2 SSD Combo (NVMe PCIe Gen3 x4 / SATA )

The Toshiba HG6 128GB you have now is SATA; the Samsung 970 PRO 512GB you want to buy is NVMe. Different connectors that fit the same socket, not different sockets.